# Swift recursive function , return type Closure

Tags: swift, recursion, closures

The following is a basic function to add or subtract based on the return function called.

```
func calculateFunc(_ inputValue:Int) -> (add:(Int)->(Int),sub:(Int)->(Int)){

    func addFunction(_ newValue:Int)->(Int){
        return inputValue + newValue
    }
    func subFunction(_ newValue:Int) -> Int {
        return inputValue - newValue
    }
    return (addFunction,subFunction)
}

calculateFunc(4).add(2)
calculateFunc(4).sub(1)
```

I don't know if the following is possible or not. Is there any concept of recursive function that can help?

calculateFunc(4).add(2).sub(1).add(9)

Comment: What's the exact goal? Just to achieve this syntax `calculateFunc(4).add(2).sub(1).add(9)`, or to do so by using functions alone?

Comment: Yes to achieve the syntax. But with closure not extension.

Comment: I've been playing around with it. I think that essentially requires a function to be able to return itself as a function. I don't think that's possible in a static type system, like Swift's

Comment: I asked a question, whose answer will lead to the answer of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/43624011/3141234

Answer (score 2):

You need to write an extension for `Int` like below

```
extension Int {
    func add(_ value: Int) -> Int {
        return self+value
    }

    func sub(_ value: Int) -> Int {
        return self-value
    }
}
```

Then you can call the functions as follows

```
let x: Int = 5
let y = x.add(1).sub(3)
```